# What is best way join 2 table?

Tags: sql, markdown, presto, amazon-athena

I have a question.
I want to find a new user who searched within 24 hours of signing up.
I have 2 tables which mean user join and searched history.
What is best way join those tables?(searched table is KST timezone and user sign up table is UTC timezone)
And, I wrote two queries, and do you think this is okay?
ps. I can't attach the image, so I upload it as a link.

**Searched history table**
[Serched history table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJHNf.png)
**User sign up table**
[User sign up table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q7hZ.png)

**Expected output**
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGRYW.png)

**My queries**

1.

```sql
select date(t1.kst_created_time), count(distinct t1.id)
from table1 as t1
inner join (
    select id, utc_created_time + interval '9' hour as utc_to_kst_created_time
    from table2
)as t2
    on t1.user_id = t2.id
    and date_diff('second', t2.utc_to_kst_created_time, t1.kst_created_time) <= 86400
group by 1
```

2. 

```sql
select
    dt, count(distinct id)
from (
    select
            date(t1.kst_created_time) as dt,
            t1.id as id,
            date_diff('second', t2.user_join_time_kst, t1.kst_created_time ) as second_diff
    from table1 as t1
    inner join (
        select id, utc_created_time + interval '9' hour as utc_to_kst_created_time
        from table2
    ) as t2
        on t1.user_id = t2.id
        and t1.kst_created_time >= t2.utc_to_kst_created_time
) as second_diff_of_t1_and_t2_created_time
where second_diff <= 86400
group by 1
```

Comment: Define "best": speed? beauty of code? something else? Do these 2 pieces of code work? If not, why not? You probably need to run and check execution plans to get meaningful answers for yourself.

Comment: What are the datatypes of `utc_created_time` and `kst_created_time`? Are they `timestamp`s, or `timestamp with time zone`?

Comment: I thought best means speed. I want to try excution plan but i used athena so i can't use explain @underscore_d

Comment: utc_created_time and kst_created_time are both timestamps @GMB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend `exists` rather than a join (since you are returning anything from the `join`ed table), and timezone translations using `at time zone`.

Assuming that the timestamps are stored as `timestamp with time zone`:

```
select date(t1.kst_created_time) kst_created_date, count(distinct t1.id) no_
from table1 t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from table2 t2
    where 
        t2.id = t1.user_id 
        and t2.utc_created_time <= t1.kst_created_time at time zone 'UTC' + interval '1' day
)
group by 1
```

This query does not require translating the timestamp from `table2`, so it should take advantage of an index on `table2(id, utc_created_time)`.